# Exchange Web Service (EWS) FindItems does not work if contact is in GAL

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, gal

I created a small application that gets *Contact* objects from an external source. Then, depending on some configurations, I have to create/upadate these contacts in a user's contact folder on our exchange server, so that the next time this user opens its MS Outlook, he sees the new contacts (on the exchange server, I have a user with impersonation capabilities, so security is not a concern).

For that, I use the `FindItems(folderId, filter, view)` method of the EWS library that works good. For the filter, I'm using the user's email address which is quite a good key... If I get a result back, this simply means that the *Contact* already exist, and that I need to do an update instead of a create. Everything works as expected until here...

BUT, I encounter a problem when the *Contact* (email address in fact) is already existing in the GAL (Global Address List). In this case, the `FindItems` method returns no result even if the *Contact* exists in the folder! It seems (this is a supposition) that the exchange server creates a link for contacts which have an email address that already exist in the GAL and not a new contact. And this could explain why the `FindItems` method does not return anything in this case. **The strange thing is that if I'm filtering on another property (for example on the combination of first and lastname), it works!**

Currently, what happens is that for each *Contact* that already exist in the GAL, a creation instead of an update is done (because the `FindItems` method returns nothing), and as a result, the same *Contact* is created X time (instead of beeing created once, and then updated X-1 time).

The question is of course, how can I know if a *Contact* exists in an exchange folder when it already exists in the GAL?

Current code:

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(5)
{
   PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties)
};
SearchFilter f = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ContactSchema.EmailAddress1, email);
FindItemsResults<Item> contactItems = _service.FindItems(folderId, f, view);
int resultCount = contactItems.Count(); // Always 0 if GAL, otherwise it works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem with an extended property by using the `SetExtendedProperty` method. In this extended field, I just put an `Id` and that solved the problem.

**But that does not explain why the search is not working with an email address**... If someone knows the answer, I'm still interested :)

The new search looks like this:

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(nb);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, _extendedPropDef);
SearchFilter f = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(_extendedPropDef, contact.Id);
FindItemsResults<Item> contactItems = _service.FindItems(folderId, f, view);
```

With this code, everything works as expected...